# Переменная типа byte

Tags: c#

Вот скажите, я уже задавал подобный вопрос про **char**, а вот про **byte**, немного не понял. Опять же вопрос, зачем он и где его использовать? Ведь он принимает очень маленькие значения...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Common Types System (CTS) есть вот такой набор integer типов [Integral Types Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx)

Каждый тип в той или иной мере может иметь свою прикладную задачу. Например, byte про который ты спрашиваешь, используется в сценариях работы с файловым вводом-выводом, т.к. файл по сути - это массив именно байт. Другой пример: у тебя есть массив данных, каждый элемент которого лежит в диапазоне 0..255, для экономии памяти ты должен будешь выбрать тип byte для элементов массива, т.к. не имеет смысла использовать 4-х байтовый int для этого. Также, если ты захочешь пройти по памяти, тебе тоже в качестве шага придется использовать байт.

Из Вики:

> В принципе, байт определяется для конкретного компьютера как минимальный шаг адресации памяти, который на старых машинах не обязательно был равен 8 битам (а память не обязательно состоит из битов — см., например: троичный компьютер). В современной традиции, байт часто считают равным восьми битам.
>
> Байт (англ. byte) — единица хранения и обработки цифровой информации. В современных вычислительных системах байт считается равным восьми битам, в этом случае он может принимать одно из 256 (2 в восьмой степени) различных значений. Однако в истории компьютеров известны решения с другим размером байта, например 6 бит. Поэтому иногда в компьютерных стандартах и официальных документах для однозначного обозначения 8-битного слова используется термин «октет» (лат. octet).
> В большинстве вычислительных архитектур байт — это минимальный независимо адресуемый набор данных.